# How to create JMeter script involving AWS SDK Calls

Tags: aws-lambda, jmeter, authorization, aws-sdk, performance-testing

How to create JMeter script involving AWS SDK Calls.
We need to install AWS SDK, so we have done it using AWS Bundles and added it to the Lib folder of JMeter, here we want to get all the authorization parameters and tokens found in AWS.

We have tried installing of the packages

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get "all the authorization parameters and tokens" from the [AWS Systems Manager Parameter Store](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/systems-manager-parameter-store.html) take a look at the relevant [code example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/java_ssm_code_examples.html)

So if you add a [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) to your Test Plan and put the following [Groovy code](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy) into "Script" area:

```
import software.amazon.awssdk.regions.Region
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.ssm.SsmClient
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.ssm.model.GetParameterRequest
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.ssm.model.GetParameterResponse

Region region = Region.US_EAST_1
SsmClient ssmClient = SsmClient.builder()
        .region(region)
        .build()


GetParameterRequest parameterRequest = GetParameterRequest.builder()
        .name(paraName)
        .build()

GetParameterResponse parameterResponse = ssmClient.getParameter(parameterRequest)
log.info("The parameter value is " + parameterResponse.parameter().value())
ssmClient.close()
```

you will see your parameter value in [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging)